# Configuring Sublime symlink

Tags: symlink, macos, sublime-text

## GOAL

Invoke sublime from the OSX BASH command line with the same Ubuntu command: `subl filename.txt` shall open filename.txt in Sublime.

## DETAILS

My instance of Sublime:

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app//Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Per [instructions \ tutorial](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal)  a symbolic link toThe symlink `/usr/local/bin/sublime` is recommended.

In order to meet the goal, the resulting symlink would be:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app//Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

## QUESTION

If `/usr/local/bin/subl` is used instead of `/usr/local/bin/sublime`, when would `subl` be problematic and why?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sublime` is not recommended, but simply the blog author's personal preference. The official [Sublime Text documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) uses `subl` and (I guess) most people do. However, you can use whatever suits you best. It won't be problematic until another software uses the same name for its binary.